# Where can I get an Unblech?

Tags: product-recommendation, cooking-bishul, appliances

An Unblech is a Blech which has a pot of water to stabilise temperature. None of the area Jewish shops sell an Unblech (also known as a k'deirah Blech).

Where can I get an Unblech, in NYC or on the internet?

---

Note: capitalisation of Yiddish words follows German grammar.

Comment: Note: this question does not seek to discuss any of the halachot of bishul beShabbat re: an Unblech.

Comment: "Capitalisation of Yiddish words follows German grammar": It does?

Comment: @SAH in this post

Comment: Note that availability might be directly reflecting rabbinik opinion that this device has no  halchik advantage over a much cheaper plain flat piece of metal.

Comment: I guess there was once some Soviet(!) movement to write Yiddish in the Latin alphabet. Maybe they did it for like a day, and maybe it followed German conventions

Comment: @user6591, regardless of halachic advantages, there is a distinct advantage to having even heat throughout the Blech, which you don't get with a regular steel sheet type.

Comment: That might be true. Assuming one wants uniform heat and not different temperature zones. Does it have any advantages over a regular electrical platta?

Comment: @user6591, yes. With a gas stove, it saves money. Furthermore, if the circuit breaker kicks off over Shabbos, you can still have warm food

Comment: Interesting. How long would it actually stay warm for? ( just curious)

Comment: Also in that extreme situation the source of warmth may be a disadvantage as you will not be able to cover the food completely to keep it warm. Just something to think about.

Comment: IIRC, there was an issue with the aluminum used in the construction deforming and oxidating which lead to a lot of vendors to stop carrying it.

Comment: Have you tried Amazon.com?

Comment: @DanF, I hadn't found anything on my search. A second search when I saw your comment turned up nothing.

Comment: @Isaac do you mean to a dangerous degree? Or it just got ugly and or unusable?

Comment: @user6591 Why would one not be able to cover the food completely because it is on a water-blech?

Comment: @SAH Hatmama. Here the water blech would be mosef hevel, adding heat. That is one of the type of hatmana which is not allowed when it's completely covered.

Comment: @user6591 Thanks. Is the full covering in this situation forbidden even if the same heat and covering were in place when Shabbos came in?

Comment: @SAH Yes. That would be problematic as well.

Answer (score 1):

I, too, want this blech. In addition to its halachic advantage (which may or may not change the way you can use it), this blech supposedly provides a lot more surface area and is good at keeping food warm at the right temperature without burning it.

Another name for the unblech is the "water blech" or "k'deirah blech." You may have better luck searching for these. Meanwhile, here is the source I have found. From [here](http://www.chowhound.com/post/keeping-food-warm-shabbos-272971):

> I have a K'deirah ("the unblech") and I love using it because it can
>   keep food nice and warm! Try contacting K'deirah Corporation, [...] 8818 N. Kolmar, Skokie 60076, (847)673-3210, and [a representative] will be
>   able to tell you where you can get it. Feel free to tell her I sent
>   you. Enjoy!

IY"H I will call her soon but if you beat me to it, please post what you learn about where to get this.

Comment: Regardless of whether her contact info has been posted elsewhere, I would refrain from posting it here, despite the fact I doubt most of our members would abuse it.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt It's a corporate number; I really don't think it's an issue. Anyway, I edited out the contact person for you.

Comment: I bought mine in a Judaica store in Teaneck. If you go into your local Judaica store and ask the people there to order one, they can probably get it.

Comment: Curious. It sounds like you could construct one yourself somewhat easily, no? If you got a large aluminum pan that had a bit of depth and covered it with a flat aluminum sheet, (essentially a custom cut regular blech) wouldn't that do the job?

Comment: @DanF I think--but am not sure--one is supposed to put water in between the two for halachic reasons?

Comment: @DanF Also--and I am really out of my depths here--there may possibly be a halchic reason that it needs to be done the other way around, i.e. with the pan turned upside-down over the blech

Comment: Indeed, one does place water between 2 metal sheets. AND, based on most opinions that I have read, one should put a piece of metal "upside down" over the blech. Don't recall specifics on that, offhand. The problem, as I gather, is that you may be boiling the water in the un-blech, so you're not accomplishing anything permissible.

Comment: SAH, did you end up calling her?