# A better way to warm up food on shabbat morning

Tags: shabbat, food, how-to, cooking-bishul

When warming up food on a hot tray on shabbat, [most poskim do not allow](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/01-10-18/) one to put the food directly on the hot tray, but rather insist on a plate or inverted pot or pan be placed on the hot tray and the food be placed on top of that. Unfortunately, even using a shallow baking sheet creates a 1 cm air gap between the food and the hot tray, and the food just doesn't get that hot. Any ideas on how to get food hot with this setup? Hotter warming tray? Different type of baking sheet? Putting the food in a different type on container?

Comment: Why does there need to be an air gap? Just get a cm thick aluminum sheet. If you need it to be a Kli, then drill a small depression near one corner to make a bizarrely shaped metal teaspoon.

Comment: @DoubleAA Would that really obviate מחזי כמבשל issues?

Comment: @joelk I have no idea how a plata is מחזי כמבשל anyway, so why not? Do you cook on aluminum sheets sitting on hot plates on counters? I don't. Is it an upside down Kli? Sure. (How deep a depression would there have to be to turn it from a sheet to a pot??) So mimanafshakh it's fine. But if the OP is seeking to implement any suggestion he should check with his rabbi first.

Comment: @DoubleAA Aluminum foil does not work halachically as it does not lift the food up at all - that's the same as resting it right on the hot tray. See the source I linked in the question - he covers that explicitly.

Comment: @Popular I had seen that. Why are you telling me that?

Comment: related? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/78394/where-can-i-get-an-unblech

Comment: Oh wait; I think I misunderstood your question.  You're not asking about putting food on a hotplate that is already hot; you're asking about putting food directly on it?